# Convert from decimal to binary - python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm having an issue with this piece of code I wrote. I'm trying to convert an integer input and print an output with its equivalent in binary base. For example for 5 it should drop an output of '101' however it just prints '10' like if it doesn't take into account the last digit. Please any comments would be greatly appreciated

```
T = raw_input()
for i in range(0, int(T)):
    n = raw_input()
    dec_num = int(n)
    cnv_bin = ''
    while dec_num//2 > 0:        
        if dec_num%2 == 0:
            cnv_bin += '0'
        else:
            cnv_bin += '1'
        dec_num = dec_num//2
    print cnv_bin[::-1]
```

Comment: I don't know python but if you can convert **C** code to **Python** then you can see the link - [Decimal to Binary conversion in C](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/08/c-program-to-convert-from-decimal-to-binary-number-system.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while dec_num//2 > 0:
```

should be:

```
while dec_num > 0:
```

The first time through the loop, `5//2==2`, so it continues.
The second time through the loop, `2//2==1`, so it continues.
The third time, `1//2==0` and the loop quits without handling the last bit.

Also, you can just do the following to display a number in binary:

```
print format(dec_num,'b')
```

Format string version:

```
print '{0} decimal is {0:b} binary.'.format(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the build-in function bin()?
eg:

```
bin(5)
```

output

```
0b101
```

If you don't want the prefix(0b), you can exclude it.

```
bin(5)[2:]
```

hope to be helpful!

Comment: thanks a lot! actually the assignment was to use find the binary equivalent without using the formula...but will keep in mind for future occasions

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def roundup(n):
    return math.ceil(n)
D = eval(input("Enter The Decimal Value: "))
n = roundup(math.log2(D+1))-1
bi = 0
di = D
qi = 0
i = n
print("Binary Value:",end = " ")
while(i>=0):
    qi = math.trunc(di/2**i)
    bi = qi
    print(bi,end = "")
    di = di - bi*(2**i)
    i = i-1
```

Comment: This is a python 3 solution, Enter a Decimal to print a Binary value